# AngularJS DELETE with Tomcat causes 405 Request method 'DELETE' not supported

Tags: rest, neo4j, tomcat8, angularjs-resource

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j Rest backend served on Tomcat (8.0.27) with Angular frontend, all served locally at http://localhost:8080/. When I try to delete a record with either $http.delete() or with $resource().delete(), tomcat returns a 405 not supported error.

However, using $http({method: 'DELETE', url: '/competitors/13'}) works fine. Unfortunately, this does not allow me to use the angular $resource service instead of $http, which is my goal. (As an aside, PUT creates the same 405 response as DELETE)

I am also able to use DELETE from command line. This works fine:

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/competitors/13
```

I have disable csrf in WebSecurityConfig in case that has anything to do with it.

I have also added readonly init-param to web.xml to try to force tomcat to accept DELETE, like so:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Proto v2 Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>proto</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>readonly</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>proto</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Since I've verified that the server is able to perform the delete, I will omit all Java code. Here is my complete .js file with the angular module:

```
var magneticApp = angular.module('magneticApp', ['ngResource'])
.controller('defaultCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $resource, baseUrl) {

    $scope.Competitor = $resource("/competitors/:id", {id: "@id"});

    $scope.listItems = function () {
        var query = $scope.Competitor.get(function () {
            console.log('inside query');
        });
        query.$promise.then(
            function successCallback(data) {
                $scope.competitors = data._embedded.competitors;
            },
            function errorCallback(data) {
                console.log('error:');
                console.dir(data);
            }
        );
    };

    /*
     * THIS DELETE FUNCTION RETURNS A 405 NOT SUPPORTED ERROR
     */
    $scope.deleteItem = function (item) {
        var query = $scope.Competitor.delete({}, item.itemId);
        query.$promise.then(
            function successCallback(data) {
                console.log('success:');
                $scope.competitors.splice($scope.competitors.indexOf(item), 1);
            },
            function errorCallback(data) {
                console.log('error:');
                console.dir(data);
            }
        );
    };

    /*
     * THIS DELETE FUNCTION WORKS PROPERLY
     */
    $scope.deleteItemWorksCorrectly = function (item) {
        $http({method: 'DELETE', url: '/competitors/' + item.itemId})
            .then(
            function successCallback(data) {
                $scope.competitors.splice($scope.competitors.indexOf(item), 1);
            },
            function errorCallback(data) {
                console.log('delete error');
                console.dir(data);
            }
        );
    };


    $scope.adjustActive = function (item) {
        item.id = item.itemId;
        console.log('adjustActive');
        console.dir(item);
        $http.post('/competitors', item)
            .success(function (data) {
                $http.get('/competitors').success(function (data) {
                    console.dir(data._embedded.competitors);
                    $scope.competitors = data._embedded.competitors;
                });
            });
    };


    $scope.addItem = function (itemName) {
        var item = {name: itemName};
        $http.post('/competitors', item)
            .success(function (data) {
                $http.get('/competitors').success(function (data) {
                    console.dir(data._embedded.competitors);
                    $scope.competitors = data._embedded.competitors;
                    //magneticApp.controller('defaultCtrl').$scope.competitors = data._embedded.competitors;
                });
            });
    };

    $scope.listItems();

});
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks.